# Count entries per time interval in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, group-by, dataset, time-series

I'd like to count entries per time interval.

Source dataset nx2

```
2001-03-23 05:01:33.347,55
2001-03-23 05:01:33.603,62
2001-03-23 05:01:33.977,32
2001-03-23 05:01:34.126,30
...
```

Example output for group count by second:

```
2001-03-23 05:01:33.000,3
2001-03-23 05:01:34.000,1
...
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add what you have tried so far. We can help you solve your programming problems, we can't do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
% dataset
data = {
  '2001-03-23 05:01:33.347', 55 ;
  '2001-03-23 05:01:33.603', 62 ;
  '2001-03-23 05:01:33.977', 32 ;
  '2001-03-23 05:01:34.126', 30 ;
};

% convert to serial date (ignoring the seconds fraction part)
dt = datenum(data(:,1), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');

% convert to group indices
[dt,~,ind] = unique(dt);

% count occurences per group
counts = accumarray(ind, cell2mat(data(:,2)), [], @numel);

% construct resulting dataset
X = [cellstr(datestr(dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF')) num2cell(counts)];
```

The result:

```
>> X
X = 
    '2001-03-23 05:01:33.000'    [3]
    '2001-03-23 05:01:34.000'    [1]
```

---

We didn't have to convert to serial date numbers, we could have also done the following:

```
% treat column as a char matrix
dt = char(data(:,1));
dt = dt(:,1:end-4);   % remove fractions of seconds

% unique entries
[dt,~,ind] = unique(dt, 'rows');

% counting
counts = accumarray(ind, cell2mat(data(:,2)), [], @numel);

% result
X = [cellstr(strcat(dt,'.000')) num2cell(counts)];
```

Comment: Hello Amro, could u please advise the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840437/data-analysis-in-time-interval

Comment: @user1724168: Have a look, I posted a solution (a modification of the above one).